# Being smart with smart pointers: avoiding shared_ptr overuse

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have come across code like

```
bool open_resource(..., shared_ptr<resource> & res)
{
   ...
   shared_ptr<resource> newResource(new resource(...));
   res = move(newResource);
   return true;
}
```

which is then called with

```
shared_ptr<resource> res;
open_resource(..., res);
```

and then, as far as I saw, res is NOT used in ways that require sharing the pointer.

Of course I immediately thought of changing

```
   shared_ptr<resource> newResource(new resource(...));
   res = move(newResource);
```

with

```
res = make_shared<resource>(...)
```

...but then I hit a roadblock. Now I can no longer advise to change the shared_ptr reference to something more basic; at least not if I want to ensure that, if the caller actually needs a shared_ptr later, the control block efficiently resides on the same allocation as the object. For this to work, it must be a shared_ptr from the beginning.

On the other side, shared_ptr is a "heavy" type; it has two counters and aliasing and all kinds of features that really seem unneeded in most calling sites. And yet if it is shared_ptr in the signature, that they have to use.

The best solution I see is to move the body of the function to a helper function, and then overload.

```
bool get_resource_parameters(Param1& param1,..., ParamN& paramN)
{
   ...
}

bool open_resource(..., shared_ptr<resource> & res)
{
   Param1 param1;
   ...
   ParamN paramN;
   if(!get_resource_parameters(param1,...,paramN))
       return false;

   res = make_shared<resource>(param1,...,paramN);
   return true;
}

bool open_resource(..., unique_ptr<resource> & res)
{
   Param1 param1;
   ...
   ParamN paramN;
   if(!get_resource_parameters(param1,...,paramN))
       return false;

   res = unique_ptr<resource>(new resource(param1,...,paramN));
   return true;
}
```

But it's really not satisfying.

Does anyone see a better, more C++ solution?

**Edit**

Yes, the C++ way would be to return the pointer rather than a bool (and check for null). I cannot overload for shared_ptr in this case, but I can then assign the unique_ptr temporary returned to a shared_ptr varaible, and the appropriate constructor will convert it.

However, this way I lose the single allocation of make_shared. can I save it?

Comment: Why not `shared_ptr<resource> open_resource(....);`?

Comment: Don't know if it fits your needs, but with standard deallocator (delete) unique_ptr is same size as a naked ptr. Minimal overhead, and clear intent in your APIs.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know, I know, but the return code / output parameters syntax is so ubiquitous that I stopped questioning it in this context. I'd propose changing it if it enabled something not possible otherwise.

Comment: It makes it so much easier to use and still allows you to check the return value in a boolean context.

Comment: what happens if you call open_resource multiple times with the same paramters? How will you guarantee consistency in your program having two copies of the 'same' resource around?

Comment: @junchopanza it's more C++, for sure. The one drawback I see is that I couldn't overload then. I'd have to have a open_shared and open_unique.

Comment: @ErikAlapää I know. I'd be more than happy to be able to use unique_ptr whenever possible, but I didn't see an easy way.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi: No, you don't need two functions: Just return a `unique_ptr` - it can be converted to a shared one on demand.

Comment: @denniskb in this case the class is a handy frontend for a set of system calls. So if you created it with the same parameters and then called its methods with the same parameters again, I guess you would just make the same system calls. In fact I guess you would be better off using different instances than the same, since you wouldn't be competing for buffers.

Comment: @MikeMB yes it can, but then you would be performing two allocations; the first for the object inside the function and the second for the shared control block after the function returns. I agree I would probably not die if I just returned a unique_ptr then converted it, but I'm curious, can we do better?

Comment: @FrancescoDondi: Ah yes, sorry. I overlooked that central requriement in your question

Comment: The question is probably, if the single allocation is actually that important. In most cases (as you said yourself) you don't need a shared pointer at all and in the cases where you do, the creation is (in my experience) rarely a performance bottleneck. Most objects that I managed by shared pointers are rather long lived and dynamic memory allocation in a tight loop is an anti pattern anyway. So I'd rather optimize for the common case (return a unique_ptr) and then, if you really encounter demand for it, add a second function that returns a shared_ptr and refactor your code accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To `allow unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr`, you may use template:

```
// Dispatcher for make_unique/make_shared
template <template <typename...> class Ptr, typename T>
struct make_helper;

template <typename T>
struct make_helper<std::unique_ptr, T>
{
    template <typename ...Ts>
    std::unique_ptr<T> operator() (Ts&&... args) const {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct make_helper<std::shared_ptr, T>
{
    template <typename ...Ts>
    std::shared_ptr<T> operator() (Ts&&... args) const {
        return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};

template <template <typename...> class Ptr, typename T, typename ... Ts>
auto make(Ts&&... args)
{
    return make_helper<Ptr, T>{}(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

And then

```
bool get_resource_parameters(Param1& param1,..., ParamN& paramN)
{
    //...
}

template <template <typename...> class Ptr>
Ptr<resource> open_resource(...)
{
   Param1 param1;
   ...
   ParamN paramN;
   if(!get_resource_parameters(param1, ..., paramN))
       return nullptr;

   return = make<Ptr, resource>(param1, ..., paramN);
}
```

And check for `nullptr` instead of split bool and smart_pointer.

Comment: This is the kind of magic I was looking for :) I don't think I had ever seen (at least not outside soon-forgot abstract examples) " template < template < ... ", or forwardings of parameter packs. Pity having to create struct to have partial specialization, though, but it's C++'s fault that.

Comment: Nice solution!  Depending on your needs, you want to consider the case where std::unique_ptr is using a custom deleter.

Comment: A more general solution would probably accept a smart-pointer factory function / lambda, so that it is not limited to these two smart-pointer types.

Answer (score 12):

`std::shared_ptr` has a [converting constructor from `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). Why don't you make the function return a `std::unique_ptr` by value:

```
unique_ptr<resource> open_resource(...);
```

This also serves as documentation that this is a factory function that transfers the ownership of the `resource` to the caller.

And let the caller decide how they want it:

```
auto x = open_resource(...);
// or
std::shared_ptr<resource> x{open_resource(...)};
```

Comment: yes it can, but then you would be performing two allocations; the first for the object inside the function and the second for the shared control block after the function returns. I agree I would probably not die if I just returned a unique_ptr then converted it, but I'm curious, can we do better?

Comment: @FrancescoDondi You can do better with `boost::intrusive_ptr` and embedding the ref-counter into the object. I would try to avoid using smart-pointers at all, if possible, in favour of by-value.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi If you are minimizing instructions and cache utilization, `std::shared_ptr` is the worst choice because of its size and atomic instructions.